# Inner shadow effect and gradient background color in flutter

Tags: flutter

I know how to use InnerShadow, but I don't know how to apply a gradient to the background color.

[Inner shadow effect in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54061964/inner-shadow-effect-in-flutter)

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQFIC.png)

Comment: I found a way to add shadows to the top and bottom.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57498128/how-to-create-a-card-with-both-an-inner-shadow-and-a-gradient-fill

Comment: the only way is to use a `CustomPaint`